# Is there anyway to access the attribute value in Raphael js?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Is there any way to compare if a text 's font size is equal to 50 inside its attribute? How can I access the attr() value in a Raphael element? For example, I have a paper.set() contains a lot of paper.text() inside, I want to know if there is one text element got the "font-size" is equal to 50 by using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you use `Element.attr(<attrName>, <attrValue>)` to set an attribute value, just use `Element.attr(<attrName>)` to retrieve the value. Note that `<attrValue>` will come back to you as text, i.e. as `"50"` not `50`.

The following snippet demonstrates this, though it may not work in some browsers (e.g. Chrome) possibly because the snippet is trying to access an external third-party library, i.e. Raphael.js. So, to run it, either use Firefox or copy it and run it on your own computer.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var paper = Raphael("holder", 200, 80);
  paper.set().push(
    paper.text(120, 20, "Hello").attr({"font-size": "40"}), // set attribute
    paper.text(120, 60, "Hello").attr({"font-size": "50"})
  ).items.forEach(function(item, itemNum) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(document.createElement("p")).innerHTML =
      "item #" + itemNum + ": " + (item.attr("font-size") === "50"); // get attribute
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael-min.js"></script>
<div id="holder"></div>
```